# Obtaining weight of evidence plugin for ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, statistics, extensions, modelling

I read  this article:

[An integrated user-friendly ArcMAP tool for bivariate statistical modelling in geoscience applications](https://www.academia.edu/30723825/An_integrated_user-friendly_ArcMAP_tool_for_bivariate_statistical_modelling_in_geoscience_applications)

but I did not find this tool "bivariate statistical modelling , BSM ".

I sent an email to its authors but they did not respond,

Is there any other way that I can obtain this tool?

Comment: Contact the author? A contact email is in the article.

Comment: Yes, I sent an email but they did not respond

Comment: Can you link to the article?

Comment: @Spacedman I added that link

Comment: @Spacedman
Yes, Sure
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/307770238_An_integrated_user-friendly_ArcMAP_tool_for_bivariate_statistical_modelling_in_geoscience_applications